# Css dropdown colour changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 dropdowns, Which are changing the colour of text on the website, The issue is once i select the text it wont let me go back, e.g. if green is the 3rd one down in the dropdown list and red is the 2nd and blue is the 1st, If i select green i cannot select the other two.

Heres my code. I should really not append to the doc body, How would you recommend me doing this another way? brain is so out of order today

js

```
   $('#titlecolorChooser').change(function() {
        $('body').addClass($(this).val());
        //document.body.className = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#textcolorChooser').change(function() {
        $('body').addClass($(this).val());
        //  document.body.className = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#locationcolorChooser').change(function() {
        $('body').addClass($(this).val());
        //document.body.className = $(this).val();
    });
```

css

```
.blue1 h3 {color:blue;}
.red1 h3 {color:red;}
.green1 h3 {color:green;}
.yellow1 h3 {color:yellow;}
.blue2 p {color:blue;}
.red2 p {color:red;}
.green2 p {color:green;}
.yellow2 p {color:yellow;}
.blue3 h4 {color:blue;}
.red3 h4 {color:red;}
.green3 h4 {color:green;}
.yellow3 h4 {color:yellow;}
```

html

```
Title Color
    <select id="titlecolorChooser" ng-model="eventData.h3color">
      <option value="">Choose a Colour</option>
      <option value="blue1">Blue</option>
      <option value="red1">Red</option>
      <option value="green1">Green</option>
      <option value="yellow1">Yellow</option>
    </select>
    Text Colour
    <select id="textcolorChooser" ng-model="eventData.pcolor">
      <option value="">Choose a Colour</option>
      <option value="blue2">Blue</option>
      <option value="red2">Red</option>
      <option value="green2">Green</option>
      <option value="yellow2">Yellow</option>
    </select>
    Location Color
    <select id="locationcolorChooser" ng-model="eventData.h4color">
      <option value="">Choose a Colour</option>
      <option value="blue3">Blue</option>
      <option value="red3">Red</option>
      <option value="green3">Green</option>
      <option value="yellow3">Yellow</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: first of all you need to understand what you did, and then the solution should be easy to achieve: when you add class to the body, it **stays there** until you remove it. the class that is located lowest on the css page will be the last processed hence once you add yellow for example, obviously it will be the last class processed and the text will always be yellow until you remove that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to solve your problem, i am going to show you one of them:

as i wrote on the comments, when you add the class it stays there until you remove it. so instead of checking each time what colored classes the body has, you can simply remove all of them and add the classes from all of the selects each change.

set a common class to all your selects, and on each change event set their values as classes to the body.

```js
 $(function() {
   $(".colorSelect").change(function() {
     $("body").attr('class', '');
     $(".colorSelect").each(function() {
       $("body").addClass($(this).val());
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
.blue1 h3 {
  color: blue;
}
.red1 h3 {
  color: red;
}
.green1 h3 {
  color: green;
}
.yellow1 h3 {
  color: yellow;
}
.blue2 p {
  color: blue;
}
.red2 p {
  color: red;
}
.green2 p {
  color: green;
}
.yellow2 p {
  color: yellow;
}
.blue3 h4 {
  color: blue;
}
.red3 h4 {
  color: red;
}
.green3 h4 {
  color: green;
}
.yellow3 h4 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Title Color</h3>
<select class="colorSelect" id="titlecolorChooser" ng-model="eventData.h3color">
  <option value="">Choose a Colour</option>
  <option value="blue1">Blue</option>
  <option value="red1">Red</option>
  <option value="green1">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow1">Yellow</option>
</select>
<p>Text Colour</p>
<select class="colorSelect" id="textcolorChooser" ng-model="eventData.pcolor">
  <option value="">Choose a Colour</option>
  <option value="blue2">Blue</option>
  <option value="red2">Red</option>
  <option value="green2">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow2">Yellow</option>
</select>
<h4>Location Color</h4>
<select class="colorSelect" id="locationcolorChooser" ng-model="eventData.h4color">
  <option value="">Choose a Colour</option>
  <option value="blue3">Blue</option>
  <option value="red3">Red</option>
  <option value="green3">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow3">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Of course this is not a perfect solution as you might have other classes on the body, but as i said this is just one of the many solutions out there.

**UPDATE:**

you dont have to append the classes to the body. you can wrap all your content in a div and append the classes to it instead if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use radiobuttons in this way.

```js
var col, el;

$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
   el = $(this);
   col = el.data("col");
   $("input[data-col=" + col + "]").prop("checked", false);
   el.prop("checked", true);
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
th:empty {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Red</th>
    <th>Green</th>
    <th>Blue</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/radio-buttons-with-2-way-exclusivity)

Answer (score 0):

For the second scenario, if there are other classes on your body tag, you may probably not want to remove all of them while adding the new classes. Below code removes only those classes which are added through the dropdown select.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#titlecolorChooser').change(function() {
              $("#titlecolorChooser option").each(function(){
              if($('body').hasClass($(this).val()))
              {
                  $('body').removeClass($(this).val());
              }
          });

         $('body').addClass($(this).val());
     });
     $('#textcolorChooser').change(function() {
           $("#textcolorChooser option").each(function(){
           if($('body').hasClass($(this).val()))
           {
                $('body').removeClass($(this).val());
           }
        });

        $('body').addClass($(this).val());
     });

     $('#locationcolorChooser').change(function() {
         $("#locationcolorChooser option").each(function(){
         if($('body').hasClass($(this).val()))
         {
              $('body').removeClass($(this).val());
         }
        });
        $('body').addClass($(this).val());
     });

    });
```